# jstree hover_node use custom data for ToolTip

Tags: json, hover, jstree

I have an MVC project and I am using jstree to show data from my database.  I have a class called TreeViewNode that I serialize into JSON for displaying my data in the jstree.  Here is my class:

```
public class TreeViewNode
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string tooltiptext { get; set; }
}
```

My jstree is working, but I cannot figure out how to access the tooltiptext.  I want to display this as ToolTip text on mouse hover.  Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#jstree').bind('hover_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

        //This works to show the id
        //alert(data.node.id);

        //This works to show the text
        //alert(data.node.text);

        //This works to show the icon text
        //alert(data.node.icon);

        //This works but shows the text as a ToolTip - I want to display tooltiptext from my class
        //$("#" + data.node.id).attr("title", data.node.text);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `data.node.original.tooltiptext` should give you the value

Comment: I ended up putting the title in my node text in the controller.  The hover_node was too much of a pain.  I also am using jQuery UI for the Tooltip functionality and it is working great.  Thanks for your time, Stephen S